# Commas in decimal SI math environment

Tags: siunitx, subequations

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{subequations}
\label{eqn:decanterholdup}
  \begin{align}
    T & = 0.1\frac{\mu}{S_H - S_L} \\
     & = 0.1 \frac{0.856551}{0.999492 - 0.88435} \nonumber\\
     & = \SI{0.7439}{\hour}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

and the resulting answer appears as `0.743,9`. How can I get rid of the comma? Also how can I make hour appear as regular text instead of italics?

relevant packages:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4, detect-display-math = true, detect-weight, detect-mode = true, math-rm, group-separator = {,} }
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: This is not the default, so there must be something in your preamble which induces this layout. Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing your problem?

Comment: I added the SI package definition in the question

Comment: The default is a thin space, so there must be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the comma, so you get it.

Be consistent with the typesetting of numbers.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\sisetup{
  group-digits=integer, % <--- added
  group-minimum-digits = 4,
  detect-display-math = true,
  detect-weight,
  detect-mode = true,
%  math-rm, % <--- removed!
  group-separator = {,}% <--- not a good choice
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
T & = \num{0.1} \frac{\mu}{S_H - S_L} \\
  & = \num{0.1} \frac{\num{0.856551}}{\num{0.999492} - \num{0.88435}} \nonumber\\
  & = \SI{0.7439}{\hour}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Beware that `math-rm` without a value is a way to get wrong output (the units will be in math italic).

[image]

Comment: what is a better choice for the group separator? and do you know how to un-italicize hours?

Comment: @inyrface Leave the default thin space. *You* are asking for an italic `h`; remove `math-rm`.

Comment: my text environment is in another san serif font. Do you know how I can make SI serif only in the math environment? or you can check out my new question.